# Force clear flow for div container

Tags: css, css-float, css-position, overflow

I use this code on my [test page](http://spideradvices.blogspot.ro/2014/01/test-4.html)  to clear header-container float, but doesn't work. Can I force it somehow?

```
#header-container{
  position: relative !important;
  clear: both !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach:

```css
#header-container:after {
  content: ' ';
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;       /* trigger hasLayout for IE 6/7*/
}
```

I also suggest to take a look at talented *Nicolas Gallagher's* **[Micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)**

### Update:

Per the OP's explanations, (at the comments below):

> That header-container floats on top and stays there when i scroll and
>   i don't want that.

[image]

That is not a *clearing fix* issue, None of `#header-container`'s children are *floated*.

The point is the `.viewitem-panel` and `.viewitem-inner` elements **are positioned** to stay at the bottom of the page, right under the header, and `.viewitem-inner` has a `overflow-y: scroll;` CSS declaration to scroll the content.

So, This problem can not be resolved unless the layout is changed.

Comment: @hashem : haha...do not use it because `display: table` mess up the layout, you only suggested me!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor :) It's different. However I withdrew my suggestion :)

Comment: @PescuVili *Well,* I don't see any problem with `#header-container`. Could you explain more?

Comment: @NoobEditor I just recommend to avoid using `table` stuff for the whole layout of the page. There's nothing wrong with `table` displayed items if they were used in a correct direction.

Comment: i need to clear float for header-container in static pages like this one http://spideradvices.blogspot.ro/2014/01/test-4.html and nothing suggested here seems to work

Comment: @PescuVili But `#header-container` has no *floated* children. clearing fix looks meaningless in this case. Please provide an image to demonstrate the issue you're facing.

Comment: That header-container floats on top and stays there when i scroll and i don't want that. Printscreen here: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-NaToceLKtJU/UueSpojnqAI/AAAAAAAABps/G1uHnFX-mMM/w674-h395-no/Untitled.jpg  What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

place `clear` in a separate class

`.clearfloat{clear: both}`

and then place it after the `div` you wanna `clear` `float`

```
<div id="header-container">
</div>
<div class="clearfloat"> </div>
```

Comment: i don't have access to my template to edit that div, i have only css access :(